# Convert stylesheet to printable format

Tags: html, css

Here is my main stylesheet code.

```
body {
background-color : #fdf4d5;
font-family : "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size : 100%;
line-height : 1.5;
text-align : left;
}
a {
text-decoration : none;
}
a:link, a:visited {
color : #C80000;
}
a:active {
background-color : #C80000;
color : #FFF;
}
.body {
clear : both;
margin : auto;
width : 70%;
}
.mainHeader img {
height : auto;
margin : 0 0;
width : 100%;
}
.mainHeader nav {
background-color : #faa01e;
border-radius : 5px;
height : 60px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {
list-style : none;
margin : 0 auto;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
color : #FFF;
display : inline;
float : left;
}
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
color : #FFF;
display : inline-block;
height : 30px;
padding : 15px 80px;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active, .mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a.visited {
background : #C80000;
color : #FFF;
text-shadow : none;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a {
border-radius : 5px;
height : 60px;
}
.mainContent {
border-radius : 5px;
line-height : 25px;
}
.content {
border-radius : 5px;
float : left;
width : 70%;
}
.content img {
border-radius : 5px;
height : auto;
margin : 0 0;
width : 100%;
}
.bottomContent {
border-radius : 5px;
padding : 3% 0;
}
.content p:first-letter {
text-transform : uppercase;
}
.content p {
color : #000;
font-family : "Adobe Caslon Pro", "Hoefler Text", Georgia, Garamond, Times, serif;
font-size : 14pt;
font-variant : small-caps;
letter-spacing : 0.1em;
line-height : 145%;
margin : 40px auto;
text-align : left;
text-transform : lowercase;
}

.boxOne {
border-radius : 5px;
float : left;
width : 30%;
}
.boxTwo {
border-radius : 5px;
float : left;
width : 30%;
}
.boxOne img {
border-radius : 5px;
height : auto;
margin : 0 0;
width : 100%;
}
.boxTwo img {
border-radius : 5px;
height : auto;
margin : 0 0;
width : 100%;
}
.mainFooter {
background-color : #FAA01E;
border-radius : 5px;
float : left;
margin : 2% 0;
width : 100%;
}
.mainFooter p {
color : #FFF;
float : right;
margin : 2% auto;
width : 92%;
}
```

I have put great effort and converted it to a printable format(print.css).Here is my print.css code.

```
body {
background-color : #FFF;
font-family : "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
width:auto;
font-size : 100%;
line-height : 1.5;
text-align : left;
}
.body {
clear : both;
margin : auto;
width : auto;
}
.mainHeader img {
height : auto;
margin : 0 0;
width : auto;
}
.mainHeader nav {
display:none;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {

}
.mainHeader nav ul li {

}
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {

}
.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active, .mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a.visited {

}
.mainHeader nav ul li a {

}
.mainContent {
border-radius : 0.05in;
line-height : 0.26in;
width:auto;
}
.content {
border-radius : 0.05in;
float : left;
width : auto;
}
.content img {
border-radius : 0.05in;
height : auto;
margin : 0 0;
width : auto;
}
.bottomContent {
border:none;
width:auto;
}
.content p:first-letter {
text-transform : uppercase;
}
.content p {
color : #000;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size : 14pt;
font-variant : small-caps;
letter-spacing : 0.1em;
line-height : 145%;
margin : 0.42in auto;
text-align : left;
text-transform : lowercase;
}
.boxOne {
display:none;

}
.boxTwo {
display:none;
}
.boxOne img {

}
.boxTwo img {

}
.mainFooter {
background-color : #FFF;
border-top: 0.02in solid #000000;
float : left;
margin : 2% 0;
width : 100%;
}
.mainFooter p {
color : #FFF;
float : right;
margin : 2% auto;
width : 92%;
}
```

I tried my level best but I don't know whether this is correct or not.The reason is that I don't have a clear understanding about this concept.If you can please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: You should see it attached to the html page you want to print and see if it suits. There's no "conversion rule" from a stylesheet to "printable format". It all depends on the information displayed on the page and on the result you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much.But still I'm confused.

Comment: CSS describes the aspect of the elements in the page. It's up to you decide what the aspect should be like, so there's no way of saying it's correct. CSS is quite easy to understand, more difficult to master, but I think some tutorial/documentation might be good. Take a look at MDN at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure you are applying the appropriate stylesheet to the appropriate medium. You could do this with the `media` attribute on your `link` element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" media="screen">
```

This will ensure you don't pollute your print stylesheet with styles intended for a browser. Now, do a `Print Preview` with your browser. If you don't have any styles being applied for your print medium, you should see a pretty bland page. That's good. Figure out how you want the printed page to look, and build a print stylesheet and link to it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

You can add to the print stylesheet and continue to check `Print Preview` in your browser, but I would recommend investigating Firefox and the Web Developer plugin (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) that will allow you to apply different styles from different mediums right from your browser.

Finally, I should note that if you want a stylesheet to be applied across mediums (which could, perhaps, define a font face), you should link to that stylesheet by either not applying the `media` attribute, or applying the `all` value to it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css" media="all">
```